# primary key value EF Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, primary-key

I need to get a primary key value before it will be assigned to the model by EF Core.

My Model:

```
**namespace Tree.Models
{
  public class MeterLocationTree
  {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LocationElement { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int[] Path { get; set; }
  }
}**
```

My migration snapshot for the model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Tree.Models.MeterLocationTree", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("integer")
                        .HasAnnotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("LocationElement")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("text");

                    b.Property<int[]>("Path")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("integer[]");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("MeterLocationTree");
                });
```

Is it possible to get the current primary key value before it will be assigned to the model during Add operation? 
So maybe we can have access to the ef mechanism of primary key values generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model contains data and we cannot access the value before it is assigned to model in EF core.